# Visual Studio 2019 Cross Platform debugging doesn't work on remote system when C++ shared items project is used

Tags: c++, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019

Without C++ Shared project everything works fine.

Steps to reproduce:

- create a blank solution
- add a new C++ Shared Items project called SharedProject
- add a new C++ Linux project MainProject
- reference the SharedProject to the MainProject
- add main.cpp (#include  int main(){ std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; return 0; })
- check if everything builds fine

try to run this by pressing F5.

error:

"Could not start debugging. The program to debug '~/projects/MainProject/bin/x64/Debug/MainProject.out' does not exist on the remote system. If overriding the program to debug in the Property Pages, please make sure the file exists on the remote system. If the project has not been built before please make sure to build it and that the build completes successfully."

project is compiled fine on the remote system but executable file path is ~/projects/MainProject/MainProject/bin/x64/Debug/MainProject.out

By having the shared item project visual studio adds an extra directory 'MainProject'.

in ~/project/ folder on the remote system we have:

```
  MainProject
  MainProject
    bin/...     
  SharedProject
    bin/...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

add Remote post-build event with the following cmd

```
mv ~/projects/MainProject/MainProject/* ~/projects/MainProject/
```